# Correct design pattern for invalidating cache after service bus event

Tags: .net-core, design-patterns, architecture, azureservicebus

Let's say I have two applications: Web API, and Web UI. They are both using the same product database. The business case is very read-intensive (via API) with rare writes (via Web UI). Therefore on the API side there exists singleton `ProductCatalog` service, which holds most of the active parts in memory as object graph and applies business logic rules to serve read requests. When someone use WebUI to make changes in catalog, I want to update/invalidate the cache inside this service. I will use service bus (Azure Service Bus) to propagate this event.

What is the correct design pattern on Web API side to do this?

- it feels bad for `ProductCatalog` to implement subscription to service bus
- it also feels weird to expose some `InvalidateCache` method on this service to be called by someone else
- should there be some component to encapsulate service bus subscriber, and expose incoming messages as regular .NET events? Should this component be therefore dependency (injected) of `ProductCatalog`, so it can subscribe to these events?

Is there some good example of .NET implementation of something like this?

Answer (score 0):

May want to consider extracting the `Cache` and placing it somewhere the `ProductCatalogService` can access.

Generally when data changes:

1. When the `Service Bus` message is received, the `Cache` should be invalidated.
2. When the `Cache` should be invalidated, a `Subscriber` to that event is notified.
3. The `Subscriber` uses a `Product Data Retriever` to get new `ProductData` and then the `Subscriber` updates the `Cache`.

General steps the `ProductCatalogService` takes when reading data:

1. Decide whether to simply always accept cached data or have it detect/wait for `Cache` to be updated.
2. Get data from `Cache`.

With this, `ProductCatalogService` should no longer be a singleton, and doesn't have to be assuming the cached data was the only reason it was designed that way.

The challenge is in the `Cache`. Make it thread safe or use a cache management solution that handles this stuff itself.

An overview of these items ([eraser](https://www.tryeraser.com)):

[image]

Learn more about the ASP.NET Core Memory Cache here (the docs say its thread safe): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-6.0